# SwiftUI value always defaultValue in PreferenceKey

Tags: swiftui, scroll

In SwiftUI, I have a struct inherit from `PreferenceKey` to follow current scroll offset and previous scroll offset, but `value` always `defaultValue`, but I want to `value` be assigned to previous value, can you fix to me, there my code:

```
struct ScrollOffsetChangePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Value =  .init(current: .zero)
    
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        let newValue = nextValue()
        value = .init(current: newValue.current, previous: value.current)
    }
}

extension ScrollOffsetChangePreferenceKey {
    struct Value: Equatable {
        let current: CGPoint
        let previous: CGPoint?
        
        init(current: CGPoint, previous: CGPoint?) {
            self.current = current
            self.previous = previous
        }
        
        init(current: CGPoint) {
            self.current = current
            self.previous = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I try change defaultValue in reduce, but I think this not good, I expected value will change in each reduce method